# Options for letting Team Foundation Server 2015 do code coverage

Tags: c#, tfs, code-coverage, tfs-2015

I have a TFS 2015 server which needs to perform code coverage of my C# code.

I tried a few thing, which works to some extend, but not at all optimal:
* I installed `NUnit.WithFramework`, along with `OpenCover` and `ReportGenerator`, and had it publish an artifact with htm files in - that showed me the coverage, but a lot of clicks were required to see it. And it is not shown in the dedicated field for code coverage:

[image]

What is needed for it to show my code coverage? Is a Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on my server required?

No way anything else can build and show my code coverage?

**Update:**

When running the build, the following warnings are thrown:

```
2016-07-06T08:30:31.0461215Z Warning: Using Isolation mode to run the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.

2016-07-06T08:30:34.3147483Z Warning: Diagnostic data adapter message: Could not find diagnostic data adapter 'Code Coverage'.  Make sure diagnostic data adapter is installed and try again.
```

It appears I need a *diagnostic data adapter*, which are [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286727.aspx) - I will try to apply such to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Install a Visual Studio on the build server which is a requirement it seems for code coverage results to be returned.

Microsoft Visual Studio is required to be installed on the build server for the following scenarios:

- To build any CPP test project, you must install Visual Studio
  Professional or later.
- To run unit tests, or coded UI tests, you must install Visual Studio
  Professional or later.
- **To use data and diagnostic data adapters:**

> **Code coverage: Visual Studio Premium or later.**
>   Test impact:
>   Visual    Studio Ultimate.
>   IntelliTrace: Visual Studio Ultimate.

- To build any modern style apps on a build machine: Visual Studio
  Ultimate or Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 (Operating system on
  build server must be Windows 8).
- To compile and run tests for a project with a faked assembly: Visual
  Studio Ultimate

Please see the source link from MSDN: [Run tests in your build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Comment: As long as you have MSDN there is no additional licence for Visual Studio required on a Build Agent.